# Configure Opencv in Netbeans

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

**I want to run following piece of code on my Kubuntu 14.10:** 
https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/video/bg_sub.cpp

**I get the following error message:**
In file included from main.cpp:9:0:
/usr/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp:46:28: fatal error: opencv2/core.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/core.hpp"
                            ^
compilation terminated.

my current opencv version is: 2.9.4 when I use the following command  pkg-config --modversion opencv

best regard,
jester

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Right click on project -> properties

Go to Build -> linker

and on libraries add opencv